# Analogue $(document).on('event', 'selecton', function(){}); for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

In jQuery there is the script

`$(document).on('click', '#popup-pers .mfp-close', function(e){});`,

is used if .mfp-close is virtual element that appear not by load the page, but by event, instead

`$(#popup-pers .mfp-close).click();`

I need the same analogue for JS. I use

```
pers_hide = querySelector('#popup-pers .mfp-close');
```

but browser sees just `#popup-pers` , not `'#popup-pers .mfp-close'`

Comment: PS, `$(document)` as a delegator is never a good idea. `$("#someKnownStaticParent")` is.

Answer (score 0):

For **dynamically created elements** on whom you want to assign a click event before they are inserted in the DOM - Assign the event to the parent **delegator**, and than query the Event `Event.target.closest(selector)` matches the desired **dynamic child** selector.

Here are two possible solutions/suggestions:

#### Create your own `on()` helper:

```js
// DOM utility functions:
const el = (sel, parent) => (parent ||document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, props) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);

// On handler:
const on = (eventName, delegator, target, cbFn, opts) =>
  el(delegator).addEventListener(eventName, evt =>
    evt.target.closest(target) && cbFn(evt), opts);

// Task:

// 1. Assign events beforehand:
on("click", "#popup-pers", ".mfp-close", (evt) => {
  console.log(evt.target.textContent);
});

// 2. Insert element afterwards:
el("#popup-pers").append(elNew("button", {
  type: "button",
  className: "mfp-close",
  textContent: "CLICK"
}));
```

```css
#popup-pers {
  background: gold;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-pers"></div>
```

#### Assign the event when creating your elements

Otherwise assign the desired event handler function **on Element creation**, by using the `onclick` method (which is the only valid way that property should ever be used, and that's when creating new in-memory elements):

```js
// DOM utility functions:
const el = (sel, parent) => (parent ||document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, props) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);

// Task:
// Insert element with click function assigned:

el("#popup-pers").append(elNew("button", {
  type: "button",
  className: "mfp-close",
  textContent: "CLICK",
  onclick() {
    console.log(this.textContent);
  }
}));
```

```css
#popup-pers {
  background: gold;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-pers"></div>
```